# {% include %} doesn't pass " for loop " data in other html pages - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i want pass data from an html page that i use `for loop` inside this page and show all data in other html pages so i tried this but it doesn't pass for loop data from my model why

side_bar_good_posts.html :

```
      {% for post in best_posts %}
  <div class="card rounded mx-auto d-block" style="width: 18rem;margin-bottom:50px;border-color:#7952b3">

  <div class="card-body" id="mobile_design_card">
    <a href="{{post.url}}"><p class="card-text" id="mobile_design_card_name">{{ post.name }}</p></a>
  </div>
  <a href="{{post.url}}"><img src="{{ post.get_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="290px" width="300px"></a>

  </div>
&nbsp; &nbsp;
    {% endfor %}
```

views.py :

```
from .models import BestArticals

def Best_Articals(request):
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()
    context = {'best_posts' : best_posts}
    return render(request,'android/side_bar_good_posts.html',context=context)
```

in other html pages :

```
{% include "android/side_bar_good_posts.html" with best_posts=best_posts %}
```

it show just html tags , but data from for loop doesn't appear why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i fixed the problem thanks for everybody help me .

- in views.py you must add this line in every `def` or `class` if you want use `{%include with for loop and all data %}` in all html pages

add this line in all `def or class in views.py` :

```
best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all() # this is my model name called BestArticals replace name to yours
```

then follow the steps bellow

in my case this is my full code

views.py :

```
def android_posts(request,slug):
    android_posts = get_object_or_404(Android, slug=slug)
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all() # this line you must add it to all def in views
    context = {'android_posts':android_posts,'best_posts' : best_posts} # and here put best_posts or yours 
    return render(request,'android/android_posts_page.html', { 'android_posts': android_posts,'best_posts' : best_posts }) # and here put best_posts or yours 

def Best_Articals(request):
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()
    context = {'best_posts' : best_posts}
    return render(request,'android/side_bar_good_posts.html', context)
```

side_bar_good_posts.html :

```
make your own design

      {% for post in best_posts %}
  <div class="card rounded mx-auto d-block" style="width: 18rem;margin-bottom:50px;border-color:#7952b3">

  <div class="card-body" id="mobile_design_card">
    <a href="{{post.url}}"><p class="card-text" id="mobile_design_card_name">{{ post.name }}</p></a>
  </div>
  <a href="{{post.url}}"><img src="{{ post.get_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="290px" width="300px"></a>

  </div>
&nbsp; &nbsp;
    {% endfor %}
```

in other html pages that where you want to use include :

```
{% include 'android/side_bar_good_posts.html' with best_posts=best_posts %}
```

and everything will work fine !

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your concern, you want to include a **partial html** `android/side_bar_good_posts.html` in many pages.

that's been said, the trick is to pass `best_posts` along with other variables/sets (e.g `posts` for blog app) in the context and once available in `template` context you then pass it (`best_posts`) again to the `include` using `with`.

below how to do that the wright way.

let say you have a `blog` and `home` apps, the project structure should be like

```
.yourproject

  .. home
     .. templates
        .. home
           .. index.html
     .. views.py


  .. blog
     .. templates
        .. blog
           .. post_list.html
           .. post_detail.html
        .. includes  # the folder that will hold all 'blog' app related html partials
           .. side_bar_good_posts.html  # as good naming prefer the rails way: 
                                        # prefixing partials with '-'
                                        # e.g: _good_posts.html
     .. views.py


   .. templates  # Global project templates
      .. base.html
```

in `blog/views.py`

```
from .models import Artical, BestArticals  # import 'Artical' Model

def post_list(request):

    posts = Artical.objects.all()  # fetch all posts, you may add pagination ..

    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()

    context = {
        'posts' : posts,
        'best_posts' : best_posts
    }
    return render(request,'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

in `blog/templates/blog/post_list.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

..

<aside class="..">
{% include 'includes/_good_posts.html' with best_posts=best_posts %}
</aside>
..
```

in `blog/templates/includes/_good_posts.html`:

your code as is, just renamed `post` to `best_post` to be consistent and avoid any conflict with other variables that may have the same name

```
{% for best_post in best_posts %}
  <div class="card rounded mx-auto d-block" style="width: 18rem;margin-bottom:50px;border-color:#7952b3">

  <div class="card-body" id="mobile_design_card">
    <a href="{{best_post.url}}"><p class="card-text" id="mobile_design_card_name">{{ best_post.name }}</p></a>
  </div>
  <a href="{{best_post.url}}"><img src="{{ best_post.get_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="290px" width="300px"></a>

  </div>
&nbsp; &nbsp;
{% endfor %}
```

and below how to include the same partial html in the home index, same logic:

in `home/views.py`

```
from blog.models import BestArticals  # import the model from 'blog' app

def index(request):

    # fetch best posts ..
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()

    [..]

    context = {
        ..,
        'best_posts' : best_posts
    }
    return render(request,'home/index.html', context)
```

in `home/templates/home/index.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

..

<aside class="..">
{% include 'includes/_good_posts.html' with best_posts=best_posts %}
</aside>
..
```

## Notes:

- `context=context` : you are passing `context` to `render()` function the wrong way, you don't need to affect it to variable
- i suggest you reviewing your logic with best articals, i think you don't need a standalone module `BestArticals`, you can use flag `featured` or depending on number of views or likes ...
- as good practices, Models name should be in single

Comment: thanks for replay , also that doesn't fix my problem it still show nothing

Comment: i think there are error in for loop or in model because of that it don't show data are you agree me ?

Comment: i'm already updating my answer, i'll be back to you.

Comment: thanks for your help it helped me >> check my answer i forget add one line in views